# Reload same block on tab change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have slider inside main block of tab and need to change it's range depending on what tab is selected.

For example, if tab1 is selected range is 1-50, if tab2 - range is 25-100.

I looked in examples how AJAX reloading for other page inside tab working and also used `handleSelect(event, tab)` event handler for changing external image on tab select, but I don't understand how can I reload content of tab without reduplicating it...

Here is example of the task with part of code: http://jsfiddle.net/QkaQq/3/

**How to work with same block in different tabs? (*I mean don't create second slider for second tab, but instead reload current one with new range when second tab is selected*)**

Comment: How come you don't want to create two sliders?

Comment: Hmmm... I think I can use two sliders in this current task, but beside sliders there will be buttons whose activity must change depending on tab selected. So this is more general question, solution I will use later in more then just one single task.